# multiple logic symbols "<" "<=" in ggplot label

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to label discrete axis values in a ggplot barchart with maths expressions. These expression indicate intervals which is why I need multiple "<" and "<=" in my label.

When trying to produce these labels using R "expression" I get an "unexpected symbol" error.
Below is the code that I have that produces the error. When removing the 2nd condition everything works fine.

```
group_name = c(expression(0 <= g[i] < 5),
           expression(5 <= g[i] <= 15),
           expression(15 < g[i] <= 20))
```

The above list is then assigned to `scale_x_discrete()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `{}`:

```
plot.new()
text(0.5, 0.5, label = expression({0 <= g[i]} < 5), cex = 5)
```

[image: resulting plot]